# Can I get the N record from set in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to get the 2nd (or 3rd, or 4th) record of a selected set using SQLite dialect.
(not the top or the last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) says:

> If an expression has an OFFSET clause, then the first M rows are omitted from the result set returned by the SELECT statement and the next N rows are returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM something
ORDER BY whatever
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2
```

Comment: Thanks. This was easy and serve the purpose